# how to find same characters words in text file

Tags: c#

I would like to find the same characters in the text like when you type the 7, it will show all words of length 7.

[image]

Comment: it same the picture

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Write an event on text typed in that particular text box, when the event is triggered find all the matching words and highlight them or do whatever you like.

Comment: I would use Regex, but it looks pretty broad/opinion based.

Answer (score 3):

Since all your words are separated by comma, you could split the unique words by comma and then use `string.Length` and `LINQ` `Where` to select all the words with the specified number of characters (in your case, it is `7`):

```
int length = 7;
string words = uniqueWordsGetFromSomeWhere.Text;
var results = words.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).Where(x => x.Length == length);
resultTextBox.Text = string.Join(",",results);
```

Note: `Trim` is added to avoid extra white characters counted.

Comment: it not all is 7, maybe you enter the 2 or 4, it will show different things

Comment: @WenjunLiu In that case. You just need to change the input `length`, obtain it from the input instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: what is "x" mean

Comment: x is the parameter passed to the lambda expression of the linq queries.

Comment: private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int length = searchl.TextLength;
            string words = filebox.Text;
            var results = words.Split(' ').Select(filebox =>filebox.Trim()).Where(filebox => searchl.TextLength == length);
            slength.Text = string.Join(" ", results);
        }

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help you via comment and because of low reputation I have, I will try to help in the answer section for that. Sorry about it.

```
static IEnumerable<string> getWordsWithMinLength(string text, int minLength)
{
    string[] words = text.Split();
    return words.Where(w => w.Length >= minLength);
}
```

Comment if u have any doubts.

Comment: That wouldn't compile since your split function parameter is not defined. Also he wants to match the exact lengths rather than equal or greater than.